# How to avoid JLabel fill parent JLabel when set opaque is true?

Tags: java, swing

I add a `JLabel2` to `JLabel1`. `JLabel1` has a background which is an image, and `JLabel2`displays text, but I also want it to display `JLabel2` background.
But when I set the opaque property of `JLayout2` to true, it fills `JLabel1` and overlaps the image. So, the question is how do I avoid it?
This is the code:

```
 JLabel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
 JLable2.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
 JLable2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
 JLable2.setFont(JLable2.getFont().deriveFont(15f));
 JLable2.setOpaque(true);
 JLabel1.add(JLable2);
 JLabel1.setOpaque(true);
```

Comment: When a component is opaque, it's no longer see through, that's the point.  I don't quite understand your setup, both labels have background images of there own?  In that case, why do you care that the second label is opaque?

Comment: My purpose is display `JLabel2` overlaps `JLabel1` while still see `JLabel1`. `JLabel2` has smaller size and has background color which use to specifies some sates.

Comment: Ah, okay, use a different layout manager other then `BorderLayout`, maybe `GridBagLayout`, this way it won't cover the entire area of `JLabel1`

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a `JLabel` inside another `JLabel`, both with background images, then the following code should work:

```
frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
JLabel l1 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("File1.jpg"));
frame.setContentPane(bg);
frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
JLabel l2=new JLabel(new ImageIcon("File2.jpg"));
b1.add(l2);
```